# How do I authenticate an npm registry from inside a Docker container in VSTS?

Tags: npm, docker-compose, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I have a Docker Compose build task build out a Node.js project on VSTS. Because we're moving to a private npm registry on VSTS, this means the Docker container needs a way to authenticate with the registry to download packages.

**Is there a way to send VSTS credentials to the Docker container so when it builds, it has access to the private npm registry?**

I thought of hard-coding VSTS's generated npm credentials into the project's `.npmrc` file, but even in that case, it wouldn't build in VSTS giving me a *"401 Unauthroized"* when doing `yarn install`:

> An unexpected error occurred: "https://[VSTS_NAME].pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/[REGISTRY_NAME]/npm/registry/ajv/-/ajv-6.1.1.tgz: Request failed \"401 Unauthorized\"".

Comment: What's the code like in .npmrc file? Do you put the token in that file? (Click 
Generate npm credentials and copy to .npmrc file)

Comment: I ended up doing that, but it has security implications, and those tokens only 3 month lifespan.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the token in the secret variable of VSTS build, then you can set the environment variable with that value through docker-compose (`-e xx=xx`).

[Setting environment variables with ‘docker-compose run’](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#setting-environment-variables-with-docker-compose-run)

With this way, you can use that environment variable to update the .npmrc file in docker.

You also can update the .npmrc file before calling docker-compose during the vsts build.